# Qt, remove dashed rectangle on selection without reimplementing paint

Tags: qt, pyqt, selection, pyside

I've seen this link:

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/15089-QGraphicsView-change-selected-rectangle-style

from this post:

[QT 4.5 - Changing the selection marquee for QGraphicsItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604995/qt-4-5-changing-the-selection-marquee-for-qgraphicsitem)

But I'm wondering if there are other options for getting rid the dashed rectangle without reimplementing paint.  This is important so I can keep PyQt and PySide routines painting fast but still have the look I want.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, if you do not want the selection rectangle, you will have to reimplement the paint method. It's not using styles or anything like that. The *only* thing you can change is that the rectangle uses QStyleOptionGraphicsItem::palette.windowText().color() as the basis color. But after that ... just a solid line being drawn, then a dashed line.

The best solution really is going to be reimplementing paint. I doubt you would ever see a performance hit from this modification.

I'm assuming you actually want to keep your items selectable. If you disable that flag on your item `setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, false)`, then it won't be able to be selected, and thus, will not display the border.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  I've reimplimented paint in C++ for now (super simple), but I was hoping to stay inside python mainly for ease of packaging.  Painting QGraphicsItems in python does seem to be a performance issue when you've got lots of items to paint, which I have.