# ItemClipsToShape QGraphicsSVGItem

Tags: python, svg, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicssvgitem

The following flag does not do what it is meant to and clip the shape.  Instead it creates a rectangular selection.

```
self.setFlag(self.ItemClipsToShape)
```

[image][image]

How can I make the selection clip to the shape?

> test.svg

```
<svg viewBox='0 0 108 95' 
xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
<g transform='scale(0.1)'>
        <path id="p2" fill='blue' stroke='red' d='M249,699v43h211v-43h-64l-2,3l-2,4l-4,3c0,0-1,2-2,2h-4c-2,0-3,0-4,1c-1,1-3,1-3,
                        2l-3,4c0,1-1,2-2,2h-4c0,0-2,1-3,0l-3-1c-1,0-3-1-3-2c-1-1,0-2-1-3l-1-3c-1-1-2-1-3-1c-1,0-4,
                        0-4-1c0-2,0-3-1-4v-3v-3z'/>
    <path id="p3" fill='blue' d='M385,593c0,9-6,15-13,15c-7,0-13-6-13-15c0-8,12-39,14-39c1,0,12,31,12,39'/>
</g>
</svg>
```

> svg_mouse.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtSvg import QGraphicsSvgItem, QSvgRenderer

class SvgItem(QGraphicsSvgItem):

    def __init__(self, id, renderer, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.id = id
        self.setSharedRenderer(renderer)
        self.setElementId(id)
        bounds = renderer.boundsOnElement(id)
        self.setPos(bounds.topLeft())
        #self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True) #horrible selection-box

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: 'QtWidgets.QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent'):
        print('svg item: ' + self.id + ' - mousePressEvent()')
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event: 'QtWidgets.QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent'):
        print('svg item: ' + self.id + ' - mouseReleaseEvent()')
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

class SvgViewer(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._renderer = QSvgRenderer()
        self.setScene(self._scene)

    def set_svg(self, data):
        self.resetTransform()
        self._scene.clear()
        self._renderer.load(data)
        item1 = SvgItem('p2', self._renderer)
        self._scene.addItem(item1)
        item2 = SvgItem('p3', self._renderer)
        self._scene.addItem(item2)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: 'QtWidgets.QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent'):
        print('SvgViewer - mousePressEvent()')
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event: 'QtWidgets.QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent'):
        print('SvgViewer - mouseReleaseEvent()')
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.viewer = SvgViewer(self)
        vb_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vb_layout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        img = b'''
                <svg viewBox='0 0 108 95' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
                    <g transform='scale(0.1)'>
                        <a href=""><path id="p2" d='M249,699v43h211v-43h-64l-2,3l-2,4l-4,3c0,0-1,2-2,2h-4c-2,0-3,0-4,1c-1,1-3,1-3,
                            2l-3,4c0,1-1,2-2,2h-4c0,0-2,1-3,0l-3-1c-1,0-3-1-3-2c-1-1,0-2-1-3l-1-3c-1-1-2-1-3-1c-1,0-4,
                            0-4-1c0-2,0-3-1-4v-3v-3z'/></a>
                        <path id="p3" d='M385,593c0,9-6,15-13,15c-7,0-13-6-13-15c0-8,12-39,14-39c1,0,12,31,12,39'/>
                    </g>
                </svg>'''
        self.viewer.set_svg(img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 600, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Actually I ran your test and now I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean the selection rectangle doesn't follow the actual item path? I don't think that has anything to do with clipping. To get a custom selection highligh you'd need to re-implement the `paint()` method and draw the highlight yourself.  https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/15089-QGraphicsView-change-selected-rectangle-style  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604995/qt-4-5-changing-the-selection-marquee-for-qgraphicsitem There's also re-implementing `QGraphicsItem::shape()`, though I'm not sure that affects the selection marquee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that QGraphicsSvgItem uses the bounds rectangle for its shape.

A possible *hacky* but effective solution is to do what QGraphicsPixmapItem does, that is to get the mask and use the alpha region for to return the `shape()` of the element.

Note that I'm not setting the ItemClipsToShape flags, because there's no need for it.
I also implemented the correct selection outline, based on the [Qt implementation](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtsvg/src/svg/qgraphicssvgitem.cpp.html#_ZL33qt_graphicsItem_highlightSelectedP13QGraphicsItemP8QPainterPK24QStyleOptionGraphicsItem).

[image: clipping and selection]

```
class SvgItem(QGraphicsSvgItem):

    def __init__(self, id, renderer, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.id = id
        self.setSharedRenderer(renderer)
        self.setElementId(id)
        bounds = renderer.boundsOnElement(id)
        self.setPos(bounds.topLeft())
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)


        # create an image based on the item size
        img = QtGui.QImage(bounds.size().toSize(), QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        # clear its buffer (this is important!)
        img.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        # create a qpainter and ask the renderer to render it
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(img)
        renderer.render(qp, id)
        qp.end()

        # create the mask by adding a QRegion based on it
        mask = img.createAlphaMask()
        shape = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        shape.addRegion(QtGui.QRegion(QtGui.QBitmap.fromImage(mask)))
        # a QBitmap based region can be unnecessarily complex, let's
        # simplify it
        self._shape = shape.simplified()

    def shape(self):
        return self._shape

    def paint(self, qp, option, widget):
        # keep track of the selected state and call the base painting
        # implementation without it
        selected = option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected
        option.state &= ~QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected
        super().paint(qp, option, widget)

        if selected:
            # draw the selection based on the shape, using the right
            # amount of contrast with the background
            fgcolor = option.palette.windowText().color()
            bgcolor = QtGui.QColor(
                0 if fgcolor.red() > 127 else 255, 
                0 if fgcolor.green() > 127 else 255, 
                0 if fgcolor.blue() > 127 else 255, 
            )

            qp.setPen(QtGui.QPen(bgcolor, 0, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
            qp.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush)
            qp.drawPath(self._shape)

            qp.setPen(QtGui.QPen(option.palette.windowText(), 0, QtCore.Qt.DashLine))
            qp.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush)
            qp.drawPath(self._shape)
```

Comment: Ah, a mask from QImage, good idea! Though unfortunately the selection will still be the `boundingRect()` I'm afraid.  https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtsvg/src/svg/qgraphicssvgitem.cpp.html#_ZN16QGraphicsSvgItem5paintEP8QPainterPK24QStyleOptionGraphicsItemP7QWidget  and follow link to `qt_graphicsItem_highlightSelected` which unfortunately doesn't use `shape()` (I don't know why, seems it would be just as easy to draw that since it's a QPainterPath already!).

Comment: So one would need to re-implement `paint()` and also the highlight drawing routine (but it would be fairly easy once the `shape` is known).

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean... but, actually it's clipping the selection marquee to the shape, the selection isn't following the shape. Subtle difference, but leaves rendering artifacts.  Try setting `self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)` and then move the drop over the bigger area... it'll be more obvious I think.  May be acceptable, of course.

Comment: Also seems like the image shape mask is causing some "jaggies" around the rounded edges... not anti-aliased. It's more obvious if the give the shapes colors and outlines (like in the SVG code posted above the actual MRE code).

Comment: Ok, I got it. I forgot that ItemClipsToShape does not behave very well with non vertical/horizontal lines as the paint clipping is not antialiased, and we actually don't need that flag anyway. I updated the example with the selection too. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Very nice! If I may suggest, adding some AA render hints to both QPainter uses (with shape calc and paint()). It comes out a bit nicer IMHO.

Comment: Hacky?? I would say a thing of beauty.I never would have thought of it and it works as expected... Well thought out and explained.. Thanks.. I just have one question.. In the comments you state  ::  `# clear its buffer (this is important!)` ::  Does the line `img.fill(Qt.transparent)` clear the buffer by making it transparent or is this an error in the comments?.

Comment: @MaximPaperno the super().paint() should automatically take care of antialiasing through the svg renderer; on the contrary there could be some issues with applying it to the selection: for vertical/horizontal lines the selection would be blurred (and there's no easy way to compensate for that unless doing painful path splitting to check for those strict lines) and that wouldn't be consistent with the way "simpler" rectangular selections are painted: if a rect-based svg shape is drawn it would have a different selection style.

Comment: @johnashu Newly created QImages have [unitialized data](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-2) that can contain "random colored" pixels. The fill function clears all the contents by filling the image with the selected color; using `QtCore.Qt.transparent` makes it a blank image ready to be drawn upon. You can see what happens by creating a QImage some time after the app started: if I add `QtGui.QImage(80, 80, QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32).save('test.png')` at the end of the Window init the result is similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzHKD.png).